# Quickblox: Messages not saved on quickblox Admin panel

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, chat, quickblox

I am using `quickBlox` in my `Application`, We have to give sync feature in our application. so we have created a API which will call `quickBlox` API to get message's of that user, now my problem is that when ever I start new chat (chat with new user) at that time 2-3 messages are stored on Admin Panel, but rest of the message are not getting stored.

I have added save flag to in my code. can you please suggest me what can I do?

```
QBChatMessage *message = [[QBChatMessage alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *paramaterDict = [self prepareDictionaryForMessage:strURL strAttachType:strAttachType];

message.text = [paramaterDict JSONRepresentation];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
params[@"save_to_history"] = @YES;

long timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
params[@"date_sent"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",timeStamp];

[message setCustomParameters:params];
```

Comment: can you post Xcode logs of messages that are not stored in the admin panel